# gson de-serialising object array without identifier

Tags: java, gson

Im getting an error trying to take a json array to a list of objects, the exception is as below.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 170
```

here is the code i am trying to use

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Test test = new Test();

    JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(test.getFile("fieldTypes.json"), JsonElement.class);
    String result = gson.toJson(json);

    System.out.println(result);

    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<JiraField>>(){}.getType();

    JiraField[]  jiraFields = gson.fromJson(result, listType);

    for (JiraField jiraField : jiraFields) {
        System.out.println(jiraField);
    }
}
```

This is the file contents

```
[
{
"id": "issuetype",
"key": "issuetype",
"name": "Issue Type",
"custom": false,
"orderable": true,
"navigable": true,
"searchable": true,
"clauseNames": [
  "issuetype",
  "type"
],
"schema": {
  "type": "issuetype",
  "system": "issuetype"
}
},
{
"id": "timespent",
"key": "timespent",
"name": "Time Spent",
"custom": false,
"orderable": false,
"navigable": true,
"searchable": false,
"clauseNames": [
  "timespent"
],
"schema": {
  "type": "number",
  "system": "timespent"
}
}
]
```

The file is being read from the resources folder but that is working fine and the sysout is correctly showing the json contents. i assume there is something im doing wrong ?

Comment: Since you try to read `result` instead of your real textfile in your second try, could it be that the `result` is corrupt? Also can you say in which line the error occurs.

Comment: the error in the first part says BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so. turns out to be caused by un mapped fields, this is how i got it working

in the object you add the @Expose annotation for the fields you want

```
public class JiraField {

@Expose
private String id ;
@Expose private String key ;
@Expose private String name ;
@Expose private boolean custom ;
@Expose private boolean orderable ;
@Expose private boolean navigable ;
@Expose private String[] clauseNames ;
```

Then when you initialise gson, you do it like this

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

then it works :)

```
JiraFields{id='issuetype', key='issuetype', name='Issue Type', custom=false, orderable=true, navigable=true, clauseNames=[issuetype, type]}
JiraFields{id='timespent', key='timespent', name='Time Spent', custom=false, orderable=false, navigable=true, clauseNames=[timespent]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<JiraField[]>>(){}.getType();
```

I think we need to specify the JiraField[] in-order to get Array.

Comment: This one would not work too: this type token declares an array list of arrays of `JiraField`, therefore it's semantically closer to `new TypeToken<JiraField[][]>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a minified JSON according to the exception message `...at line 1 column 170...`. It would be nice if you provide both exact your exact JSON document and your mapping as well, since the posted formatted JSON now has the layout destroyed. I'm also assuming your mapping is custom and basically something like:

```java
final class JiraField {

    @SerializedName("id")
    final String id = null;

    @SerializedName("key")
    final String key = null;

    @SerializedName("name")
    final String name = null;

    @SerializedName("custom")
    final boolean isCustom = Boolean.valueOf(false);

    @SerializedName("orderable")
    final boolean isOrderable = Boolean.valueOf(false);

    @SerializedName("navigable")
    final boolean isNavigable = Boolean.valueOf(false);

    @SerializedName("searchable")
    final boolean isSearchable = Boolean.valueOf(false);

    @SerializedName("clauseNames")
    final List<String> clauseNames = null;

    @SerializedName("schema")
    final List<String> schema = null;

}
```

Note the `JiraField.schema` field type: it's a list. Trying to deserialize a list of `JiraField`s with the default Gson configuration would result into:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 170 path $[0].schema

The symptom and the column are exactly the same (however, again, I'm just assyming your JSON file is minified), but note the path `$[0].schema` you probably missed to post: it says that an array begin token `[` is expected (since the field is a `List<String>`), but was an object begin token `{`. Changing the field type to a more appropriate arbitrary `Map<String, String>` or any other custom appropriate POJO would fix it. Partially.

```java
@SerializedName("schema")
final Map<String, String> schema = null;
```

Why partially? Your type token is bound to an `ArrayList`, but you're casting the deserialization result to an array `JiraField[]`, therefore you'd get something like this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [LJiraField;

To fix it, you have to declare your `jiraFields` variable matching the deserialized value type: it's an array list, but not an array -- these are not the same in Java.

```java
List<JiraField> jiraFields = ...
```

Another note regarding deserialization is that you don't need an intermediate `json` object to deserialize from. `test.getFile` most likely returns a `java.io.Reader`, so you can pass it directly to deserialize. Summarizing all up, the following should work for you:

```java
// Immutable and thread-safe, can be instantiated once and shared
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

// Immutable and thread-safe value type, the same story, + List instead of ArrayList - interfaces are usually much better
private static final Type listType = new TypeToken<List<JiraField>>() {
}.getType();

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final Reader reader = test.getFile("fieldTypes.json") ) {
        final List<JiraField> jiraFields = gson.fromJson(reader, listType);
        for ( final JiraField jiraField : jiraFields ) {
            System.out.println(jiraField.key + " => " + jiraField.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> issuetype => Issue Type
>   timespent => Time Spent

Answer (score 0):

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<JiraField>>(){}.getType();

ArrayList<JiraField>  jiraFields = gson.fromJson(result, listType);

for (JiraField jiraField : jiraFields) {
    System.out.println(jiraField);
}
```

Try This code

Comment: This won't work either, at least as the primary solution. The OP was experiencing issues with improper mapping causing JSON parsing to expect another tokens, and that's what OP's exception is saying. But yes, this would work when OP's mappings are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<JiraField>>(){}.getType();
```

Try with this

```
JiraField[]  jiraFields = gson.fromJson(result, JiraField[].class);
```